# Oracle - REGEXP_LIKE not giving desired results

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g, case

Have a string column - COL1,containing words of different lengths separated by space,this can contain special characters as well.While deriving below logic, getting different result.

Logic:
If COL1 starts with an alphabet and ends with an alphabet and doesn't contain any special characters(can contain spaces in between) flag is 1  else flag is 0.

```
COL1            FLAG
Abc gty xyz      1
ab/c bpl ?t      0
qwr .p           0
tiotio iop       1
TItio  io/       0
abc              1
abc     xy       1
```

tried with

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(COL1,'^[a-zA-Z]$') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS FLAG FROM TABLE1;
```

but wrong outcome.

Comment: Can you define 'special character'? Anything that isn't a letter or number?

Comment: I mean non-alphabetic or non-numeric character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this fit your need?

```
select 
    col1, 
    case when regexp_like(col1, '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]$') 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end as flag 
from table1
```

The regex describes a string that starts with an alphabet character, followed by 0 to N alphabet characters or spaces, and ends with an alphabet character as well.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5625cdd3ec256c49e204eea040b93801)**:

```
COL1        | FLAG
:---------- | ---:
Abc gty xyz |    1
ab/c bpl ?t |    0
qwr .p      |    0
titio  iop  |    1
TItio  io/  |    0
abc         |    1
abc     xy  |    1
```

Comment: Tried regexp_like(col1, '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*[a-zA-Z]$'), but getting flag 0 for 1

Comment: @Leon35: my bad. I updated my answer, and added a db fiddle. This should do what you want now.

Comment: Still flag is 0.Can't figure out the issue,I'm using Oracle 12c,also Col1 is NVARCHAR2().Any other work around?

Comment: @Leon35: this works in the fiddle that I linked in my answer, as you can see. Please make sure to run the query exactly as provided.